# Is it possible to modify how IDbSet<T> transfers data to a POCO entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have this DBSet

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

and that it is used like this in my repository:

```
public virtual T GetById(long id)
{
    T t = dbset.Find(id);
    return t.Deleted ? null : t;
}
```

Let's also say there is a Name property in Category, and that Category is a POCO object.

Is there a way to modify the content of Name between the database and the POCO object? Just for the sake of having an example, let's say I want to capitalize all letters of Name in my Category POCO object. So, I could have Categories.Name = 'Books' in the database (Categories is a table in this case), and then have category.Name = "BOOKS" (where category is a POCO object) after issuing a command like:

Category category = categoryRepository.GetById(id);

Is there any way to achieve this? Is there a kind of a hook in DBSet where a function call can be inserted to transform data being transfered to a POCO object?

(Of course, I would then also need to be able to do the reverse operation when persisting a POCO objet to the database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add helper properties.  For instance, using a partial class you could do this:

```
public partial class Categories {
    public string CapitalName {
        return Name.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
Category category = categoryRepository.GetById(id);
string name = category.CaptialName;
```

Or you could create an extension method on Category.

Comment: I thought about that, and it is probably what I will end up doing, but out of curiosity I was wondering whether it was possible to adapt the data binder (the one between the data store and de models) the same way it is possible to do with the model binder (the binder transferring the data between the views (forms) and the models).

Comment: Well, you could always derive a new DbSet and override various functions, but that isn't a very wise thing to do.  EF does change tracking.  If you modify the actual data in the data set, then when SaveChanges is called then your modified data will be written over the data in the database, which is not what you want.  What you want is what's known as Calculated columns, which is where you do some transformation or calculation to it and present that data.  The only way to do that without changing the underlying data is with partial classes or extension methods.